# access ExtJS from iframe

Tags: iframe, extjs

I have an intranet web application which uses iframes. The outer web-page has a menu and an iframe. The inner webpage is loaded inside this iframe based on the selected menu item in the outer page. All the pages are using lots of ExtJS, so in order to minimize the number of times extjs library is loaded I have decided to load it only once in an outer page and reference it from the inner pages like:

```
new top.Ext.grid.GridPanel();
```

I understand that I have to use document.getElementById() function to specify renderTo. But I still got errors. Is it even possible to use ExtJs this way? And what are the other limitations?

Comment: We just load ExtJS into all pages regardless because caching should reduce the issue of loading ExtJS multiple times and saves on any sideeffects of a one-ExtJS-to-rule-them-all type setup.

Plus this is intranet, so transfer shouldn't be that much of an issue.

Comment: Agree with Lloyd. For an intranet app I would not worry about referencing Ext multiple times as needed.  KISS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't disagree more with the comments under neath the question.

Whilst Ext Js files will be cached there is a big overhead in loading the Ext app multiple times.  I've tried 4 iframes with ext in firefox and it crashes under the load.

You should be loading the content using the Updater object or via Panel.load().

Comment: Yes... When you have 4 IFrames, I believe your browser has to keep track of 4 separate DOM objects.  Your browser will not be happy.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using IFrames to load your content?  That's soooo 1995.

You are aware that there's this thing called AJAX that allows you to load separate pieces of content on at different times on the same web page right?

Are you using a Viewport at all to organize your content?  You might perhaps think about leveraging the objects in the ExtJS library to build up your page instead of embedding them into the HTML.

Comment: There are still valid cases for IFraming content and IMO always will be.  For example you may want to sandbox logic, particularly in the case where you may be including content created by a third party.

Comment: Yes, the only valid case I can think of is to handle some XSS techiques.  From the way the question is stated, I see no need for XSS.

Comment: Couldnt disagree more.  I'm currently building an application where there was no option but to use IFrames for a large bank.  3rd party content providers create their own widgets.  Now we can't load their widgets directly into the dom as they could create bugs we have no control over.  Thats a valid use case and has nothing to do with XSS.  Thanks for the downvote!

Comment: so you were consuming feeds from like, Bloomberg, Reuters. . .etc?  Gotcha.  I can see what you were up to now ... can't undo my DV... UV'd your comments.